# SQL - Query condition for future date time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im having trouble with this query. I want to not select records that have passed the SYSTIME for the current date but display records for future dates even if they have passed the current SYSTIME

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE DATE>= CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME())
   AND STARTTIME > CONVERT(time, SYSDATETIME())
```

This is the query. I know why it doesnt work but I can't think of a way to do what I stated above.

Comment: What rdbms is it? Do you also want to select records in the past?

Comment: SQL Server, for an ASP site

Comment: No I already took care of past dates, I want to display only current and future records. But for current date records only ones that are after the current system time and for future records that arent of todays date. anytime.

Comment: So starting from 00:00:00 tomorrow you want all records. From today you want all that are earlier than _now_, correct?

Comment: Do you mean [GETDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188383.aspx)?

Comment: @Oded - apparently `SYSDATETIME` has more precision than `GETDATE`

Comment: Youre right, but for today i want the records later than now uptil 00:00:00 tomorrow or future dates

Comment: Is it SQL Server 2005 or 2008+?  Each affects my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE 
  (
   (DATE = CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME() 
    AND STARTTIME > CONVERT(time, SYSDATETIME()
   )
    OR Date > sysdatetime()
  )
```

You need an or condition since date time are in different fields you must first resolve today's date and time and then all future dates regardless of time.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on what the original data types are.  Let's assume they are `date`, `time`, or `datetime`.

If you want anything in the future, then this works:

```
where [date] + starttime > sysdatetime()
```

If you want just future *dates* then try:

```
where [date] > cast(sysdatetime() as date)
```

The latter is how I interpret your question, but I'm not 100% sure that my interpretation is correct.

Comment: I think you mean `[date]` instead of `[date}`